How can I correct my logic for Stock Price Alert
I am working on creating a stock price alert system using a Telegram bot and Node.js. The stock price data is gathered from YFinance, and when a target price (TP) is reached, the bot updates the database. However, I'm encountering an issue where the status changes incorrectly, even though I am using a shouldUpdate variable to prevent this.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Status Check: The bot should first check the current 'status' in the database.
Target Price (TP) Updates: If the current stock price (fetched from YFinance) hits a target price (there are 6 types: tp1_min, tp1_max, tp2_min, tp2_max, tp3_min, tp3_max), the row.status should update to reflect the specific TP that was hit. For some plans, TP3 might not be present. The bot should stop updating once the maximum TP is reached. Additionally, if the price has hit TP3 (min)  for example and then drops back down to TP2 (min), the status should remain as TP3 (min) to reflect the highest TP achieved.
Stop Loss (SL) Handling: If a specific TP is hit, for example, TP2_min, and then the price drops and hits the Stop Loss (SL), the status should update to indicate SL Hit (TP2 hit (min)). (Sometimes when price already hit the highest TP for example TP3 max, it still update the status even though I put shouldUpdate var)

The database also contains old trading plans that are already inactive, either because they hit SL or the highest possible TP, yet they're still updating.
For example:
id|stock_code|buy_area_min|buy_area_max|tp1_min|tp1_max|tp2_min|tp2_max|tp3_min|tp3_max|sl|status|created_at

7|NASI|143|134|147|152|155|160|165|171|130|TP3 hit (max)|27/08/2024  13:40:05

Current stock price for NASI.JK is 108 which is <SL. My database contains my trading plan which is already hit a long time ago, but it's still updating for no reason
Bug1
Here's my code:
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const yahooFinance = require('yahoo-finance2').default;
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');


// Initialize the Telegram bot with polling
const bot = new TelegramBot('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {polling: true});

// Initialize SQLite database
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./tradingPlan.db', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the tradingPlan database.');
});

// Create the table if it doesn't exist
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS plans (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    stock_code TEXT,
    buy_area_min REAL,
    buy_area_max REAL,
    tp1_min REAL,
    tp1_max REAL,
    tp2_min REAL,
    tp2_max REAL,
    tp3_min REAL,
    tp3_max REAL,
    sl REAL,
    status TEXT,
    created_at TEXT
)`);

// Function to split ranges and get min/max
const getMinMax = (rangeStr) => {
    const [min, max] = rangeStr.split('-').map(Number);
    return { min, max };
};

// Handle incoming messages
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;
    const message = msg.text;

    // Regular expressions to extract data
    const stockCodeRegex = /\$([A-Z]+(?:\.JK)?)/; // Updated to handle optional ".JK"
    const buyAreaRegex = /Buy Area:\n(\d+-\d+)/;
    const tpRegex = /Target Price:\n (\d+-\d+), (\d+-\d+), (\d+-\d+)/;
    const slRegex = /SL (under|close under) (\d+)/;

    const stockCodeMatch = stockCodeRegex.exec(message);
    const stockCode = stockCodeMatch ? stockCodeMatch[1] : undefined;

    const buyAreaMatch = buyAreaRegex.exec(message);
    const buyArea = buyAreaMatch ? buyAreaMatch[1] : undefined;

    const tpMatches = tpRegex.exec(message);
    const tp1 = tpMatches ? tpMatches[1] : undefined;
    const tp2 = tpMatches ? tpMatches[2] : undefined;
    const tp3 = tpMatches ? tpMatches[3] : undefined;

    const slMatches = slRegex.exec(message);
    const sl = slMatches ? slMatches[2] : undefined;

    // Extract min and max for Buy Area, TP1, TP2, TP3
    const buyAreaRange = getMinMax(buyArea);
    const tp1Range = getMinMax(tp1);
    const tp2Range = getMinMax(tp2);
    const tp3Range = tp3 ? getMinMax(tp3) : null;

    if (stockCode && buyAreaRange && tp1Range && tp2Range && sl) {
        console.log('Extracted Data:', {
            stockCode, buyAreaRange, tp1Range, tp2Range, tp3Range, sl
        });

        db.run(`INSERT INTO plans (
            stock_code, 
            buy_area_min, buy_area_max, 
            tp1_min, tp1_max, 
            tp2_min, tp2_max, 
            tp3_min, tp3_max, 
            sl, 
            status, created_at
        ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, datetime('now'))`,
            [
                stockCode, 
                buyAreaRange.min, buyAreaRange.max, 
                tp1Range.min, tp1Range.max, 
                tp2Range.min, tp2Range.max, 
                tp3Range ? tp3Range.min : null, 
                tp3Range ? tp3Range.max : null, 
                sl, 'active'
            ], 
            function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log('Database Insertion Error:', err.message);
                }
                bot.sendMessage(chatId, `Trading plan for ${stockCode} saved successfully.`);
            }
        );
    } else {
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Failed to extract trading plan data. Please check the format.');
    }
});

// Function to check prices against the stored trading plans
const checkPrices = async () => {
    db.each(`SELECT * FROM plans WHERE status NOT LIKE '%SL%' AND status NOT LIKE 'inactive'`, async (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return;
        }

        try {
            const stockCodeWithSuffix = row.stock_code.endsWith('.JK') ? row.stock_code : `${row.stock_code}.JK`;
            const quote = await yahooFinance.quote(stockCodeWithSuffix);
            const currentPrice = quote.regularMarketPrice;

            console.log(`Current price for ${stockCodeWithSuffix}: ${currentPrice}`);

            let newStatus = row.status; // Initialize newStatus with the current status
            let shouldUpdate = false;  // Flag to determine if an update is needed

            // Define status hierarchy
            const statusHierarchy = [
                'TP3 hit (max)', 'TP3 hit (min)',
                'TP2 hit (max)', 'TP2 hit (min)',
                'TP1 hit (max)', 'TP1 hit (min)',
                'active'
            ];

            // Function to get the index of the status in the hierarchy
            const getStatusIndex = (status) => statusHierarchy.indexOf(status);

            // Check if SL is hit
            if (currentPrice <= row.sl) {
                if (row.status === 'TP3 hit (max)') {
                    // Stop updating if current status is TP3 hit (max) and price hits SL
                    shouldUpdate = false;
                } else {
                    newStatus = `SL (${row.status})`;
                    shouldUpdate = true;
                }
            } 
            // Check if any TP level is hit
            else {
                if (row.tp3_max && currentPrice >= row.tp3_max) {
                    if (row.status !== 'TP3 hit (max)') {
                        newStatus = 'TP3 hit (max)';
                        shouldUpdate = true;
                    }
                } 
                else if (row.tp3_min && currentPrice >= row.tp3_min && currentPrice < row.tp3_max) {
                    if (row.status !== 'TP3 hit (min)' && row.status !== 'TP3 hit (max)') {
                        newStatus = 'TP3 hit (min)';
                        shouldUpdate = true;
                    }
                } 
                else if (!row.tp3_max && currentPrice >= row.tp2_min && currentPrice <= row.tp2_max) {
                    if (row.status !== 'TP2 hit (min)' && row.status !== 'TP2 hit (max)' && row.status !== 'TP3 hit (min)') {
                        newStatus = 'TP2 hit (min)';
                        shouldUpdate = true;
                    }
                } 
                else if (row.tp2_max && currentPrice >= row.tp2_max) {
                    if (!row.tp3_min && row.status !== 'TP2 hit (max)') {
                        newStatus = 'TP2 hit (max)';
                        shouldUpdate = true;
                    } 
                }
            }

            if (shouldUpdate) {
                db.run(`UPDATE plans SET status = ? WHERE stock_code = ?`, [newStatus, row.stock_code], function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log(`Updated status for ${row.stock_code} to ${newStatus}`);
                    }
                });
                updatePlanStatus(row.id, newStatus);
                bot.sendMessage('-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', `Plan ${row.stock_code} status: ${newStatus}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error fetching quote for ${row.stock_code}: ${error.message}`);
        }
    });
};


// Function to update the status of a trading plan and send a notification
const updatePlanStatus = (id, status) => {
    db.run(`UPDATE plans SET status = ?, created_at = datetime('now') WHERE id = ?`, [status, id], function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err.message);
        }
        console.log(`Plan ${id} updated with status: ${status}`);
    });
};

// Schedule the price check to run periodically (e.g., every minute)
setInterval(checkPrices, 60000); // Check every minute

// Start the Express server (if needed for other purposes, optional)
const app = express();

// Set up EJS as the templating engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Route for the root URL
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/plans');  // Redirect to /plans
});

// Existing /plans route
app.get('/plans', (req, res) => {
    db.all('SELECT * FROM plans', [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err.message);
        }
        res.render('plans', { plans: rows });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port 3000`);

  // Self-ping every 5 minutes
  setInterval(() => {
    https.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, (res) => {
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`Received data: ${chunk}`);
      });
    }).on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Error pinging server:', err);
    });
  }, 5 * 60 * 1000); // Ping every 5 minutes
});

I tried using traditional if else like this:
For SL
if (currentPrice <= row.sl) {
    if (!row.status.includes('SL')) {  
        newStatus = `SL (${row.status})`;
        shouldUpdate = true;
    }
}

TP3 max
if (row.tp3_max && currentPrice >= row.tp3_max) {
    if (!row.status.includes('TP3 hit (max)')) {  // Only update if not already TP3 max
        newStatus = 'TP3 hit (max)';
        shouldUpdate = true;
    }
}

TP3 min
else if (row.tp3_min && currentPrice >= row.tp3_min && currentPrice < row.tp3_max) {
    if (!row.status.includes('TP3 hit (min)') && !row.status.includes('TP3 hit (max)')) {  // Only update if not already TP3 min or max
        newStatus = 'TP3 hit (min)';
        shouldUpdate = true;
    }
}

TP2 min
else if (currentPrice >= row.tp2_min && currentPrice <= row.tp2_max) {
    if (!row.status.includes('TP2 hit (min)') && !row.status.includes('TP2 hit (max)') && !row.status.includes('TP3')) {  // Only update if not already TP2 or TP3
        newStatus = 'TP2 hit (min)';
        shouldUpdate = true;
    }
}

TP2 max
else if (currentPrice >= row.tp2_max) {
    if (!row.status.includes('TP2 hit (max)') && !row.status.includes('TP3')) {  // Only update if not already TP2 max or TP3
        newStatus = 'TP2 hit (max)';
        shouldUpdate = true;
    }
}

